# How to print a single array element in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

How to print a array element at particular index in Objective-C? My code looks like this:

```
NSString *String=[NSString StringWithContentsOFFile:@"/User/Home/myFile.doc"];
NSString *separator = @"\n";
NSArray *array = [String componetntsSeparatedByString:separator];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

I'm able to print the full contents of an array at once, but I want to assign the element at each index into a string, like...

```
str1=array[0];
str2=array[1];
str3=array[0];...this continues
```

How do I do this?

Comment: hey i got the answer ... sorry ....its 
 NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:index]);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `objectAtIndex:` method.  Example:

```
NSString *str1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *str3 = [array objectAtIndex:2];
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:):

**objectAtIndex:**
Returns the object located at *index*.

```
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

**Parameters**
*index*
An index within the bounds of the receiver.

**Return Value**
The object located at *index*.

**Discussion**
If *index* is beyond the end of the array (that is, if *index* is greater than or equal to the value returned by `count`), an `NSRangeException` is raised.

Comment: hey ya.. thanks... 
But do we have any function to knw how many array elements are there in an array. , because i need to put each one of array element in a string, then do some operation with the string, then again take the next array element into same string and perform some operation on the string... likewise goes on. so i thought of using a for loop. , hence for termination condition in for loop, what should be written? help me.
its like for(int n=0; n<**??what to write here**;n++)
{
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:n];
// do some operation
}

Comment: Hey.. No problem.. I got the solution for it :)

Answer (score 0):

if this is only for debugging, you could try using po <> in the gdb.

Answer (score 0):

As of clang version 3.3, you *can* use the `[index]` notation, so

```
NSString *str1 = array[0];
```

would work now. See [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#array-style-subscripting) for details.